# psql multiline commands: How to edit previous lines?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When writing a query across several lines in psql, sometimes I realize I've made a mistake in one of the lines previously written. In the following example,

```
select * form (
etc, etc...
```

there is a mistake in the first line, but I am already writing in the second line. How to return to and edit the first line (and change "form" to "from")?  I have been unable to do this.

Having to rewrite everything because of a single mistake is very inconvenient (specially for long multiline queries).

Comment: I think you are looking for `\edit`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it has some limitations, like always bringing up the previous query (in case you meant to type a whole new query in the editor).  Otherwise, in such cases I usually make an intentional syntax error, and then edit it (either via `\e` or bringing it back from the prompt).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Absolutely. Great suggestion.  dezso: You're also absolutely right.  I found it difficult to cope for the case where you are already in the editor and decide not to run the query. You are forced to also save it with some intentional syntax error, or else the query in the current query buffer is run.  Digging on this, an alternative solution is to use \r, which abort the query, but leaves it in the history, allowing you to bring it back from the prompt, as dezso said.  Thank you all for the comments!